# Preview of Question no longer pops up on mouseover?

Tags: support

All,

In the last day or two, when I hover over a question in the main stackoverflow list, the multi-line preview that normally shows the first 4-5 lines of a question no longer pops up?  Have there been changes to this recently? Nothing that I know of in my browser has changed in the last couple of months. (FF38).

This feature was quite helpful. I can't think of any other reason it would just stop working unless there were backend changes regarding the feature.

Note, if there were changes to what script or 3rd party server provides this functionality, that may be the issue. I had tuned my browser to allow all features on stack in the past, but continue to block the 3rd party servers of `quantserve.com` and `scorecardresearch.com` (there being no need to open those holes in the past).

What say the experts? Backend change to the preview code, or something just broke on my end?

**Update -- it is working again?**

I don't know what broke, or why it broke, but after another regular FF crash, the mouseover preview of the questions has reappeared. If there was no backend change, then I guess I can chock it up to mozilla needing more coders from SO. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: No repro here with lastest stable Firefox and WIndows 7.

Comment: That's good to know. I'm running openSuSE 13.1 with FF 38.2 (ESR). It has always worked up until yesterday? Bizarre...