# Why are mouseover preview of questions no longer working?

Tags: support

Since [Preview of Question no longer pops up on mouseover?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305518/preview-of-question-no-longer-pops-up-on-mouseover) was over a year old, I don't think this is a duplicate.

Starting today (or maybe yesterday), the mouseover preview of questions on Stack Overflow quit working (Firefox 45.8esr).

I have updated Firefox from Firefox 45.7esr to 45.8esr, but otherwise I have not changed any browser settings. Has anything on the Stack Overflow backend changed related to the mouseover preview, or is this just a new Firefox 45.8esr 'feature'?

Can anyone else confirm this behavior with 45.8esr?

Comment: "Has anything on the S.O. backend changed related to the mouseover preview" A quick look at the page source reveals that the question title hyperlinks no longer contain title attributes.

Comment: Well that makes sense. I guess you would have had to know that they were there to begin with and have a bit more web savvy than this old dog to know what to look for. Is this a temporary removal or part of some larger planned change to the S.O. question list?